# Swapping <li> elements with replaceChild possible?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a list of `<li>` elements:

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="item3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Can I swap two `<li>` elements - say item1 and item2 - with the `replaceChild`, one of the DOM tree modification methods? Will it work in all browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. replaceChild would remove one from the DOM. You want `insertBefore`

```
var a = document.getElementById('item1');
var b = document.getElementById('item2');
a.parentNode.insertBefore(b, a);
```

Of course, this would only swap them if they were next to each other in the first place.

You could leverage `replaceChild` if you wanted to swap ones which were not next to each other.

```
var a = document.getElementById('item1');
var b = document.getElementById('item3');
var after_b = b.nextSibling;
var p = a.parentNode;

p.replaceChild(b,a);

if (after_b) {
    p.replaceChild(a, after_b);
} else {
   p.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Woops, I didn't look closely enough at your tags.  If jQuery is an option: you can use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) for this:

```
​$('#item2').insertBefore('#item1');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/zK2xA/), this will *move* not *copy* the element, resulting in a swap.

Comment: That's jQuery is it? There are so many libraries that key everything off a variable called `$`. Sigh.

Comment: @David - Yes you're right, updated, I was thinking of `.replaceWith()` and didn't even look at the tags: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @David Dorward: but the only one that really matters is jQuery.   :-p

Comment: I have to accept David's answer because of the way I put my question. After all, I asked how I could do it with DOM tree modification methods. However, the jQuery one-liner is definitely the way to go for me. Thanks!